# How to interpret this LASSO regression figure?

Tags: regression, lasso

I ran one of the models replicating from a paper modifying to my data so this comes out

[image: figure]

I would like to know Im making the right statement or not

"The two strongest predictors were the presence of PC4,PC3,PC5,PC1 along with IDH1 from the gene expression data." Is this a correct statement in statistical sense ?

Other question is I would like to know how do I interpret those model coefficients here? and after PC10 the lasso penalty lines flattens if i understand correctly it means those variables were not the features i should be looking at ?

Comment: this should probably be explained in the paper you are replicating or in the documentation. For me the graph is trying to show too many things at the same time. Coefficients depend on the penalty, so I don't know how can you have different penalties and only one set of coefficients.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms6901/figures/3 I would request you to have a look 'Coefficients depend on the penalty, so I don't know how can you have different penalties and only one set of coefficients' can u explain me this